# Search numeric or string value as wildcard in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a requirement to implement search functionality in our webpage. The logic is as follows,

1. If the user enters a numeric value i.e staffid then `wildcard` to applied on the staffid column of staff `table`.
2. If the user enters a string value i.e staffname then `wildcard` to be applied on the staffname column of staff `table`.

how to implement the above scenario is sql server?.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Better have 2 parameters with appropriate type.

Comment: Logic : if you can convert inputted string to int,then pass as parameter1,else pass as parameter 2
Parameter1 will be used for searching staffid column, parameter2 for searching staffname column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have mentioned the better way is to have 2 parameters and branch search depending on which is filled or do it one query. But if you insist this is how you can do this:

```
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(10) = 'jo'
--DECLARE @p VARCHAR(10) = '34'

DECLARE @t TABLE(StuffID INT, Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1234, 'Michael Jordan'),
(7845, 'Scottie Pippen'),
(6541, 'Dennis Rodman'),
(1987, 'Phil Jackson')

SELECT * FROM @t
WHERE (@p NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND StuffID LIKE '%' + @p + '%') OR
      (@p NOT LIKE '%[^a-z]%' AND Name LIKE '%' + @p + '%')
```

This can be read as: if `@p` doesn't contain symbols other than digits search in `StuffID` column or if it doesn't contain symbols other than chars search in `Name` column.